# How to check snowflake jar version in talend studio

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend, tms

How to identify the current version of snowflake jar used by Talend studio?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

[image]

Create a connection component with snowflake connection parameters required.
in tjava, give the following and print it:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(context.jdbc_url_snowflake, 
 context.connection_snowflakeETL_userPassword_userId,    
 context.connection_snowflakeETL_userPassword_password);
System.out.println("Version: " + con.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());
```

ans: Version: 3.13.30

Option 2:

In Talend Studio, go to Windows --> show in --> click and modules --> search as snowflake